# How can I get the count of values in one column in a DF in another DF's column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a consequent DF like this:

```
consequents
___________
['a']
['b']
['c']
```

and another item DF like this

```
items
_____
['a', 'b']
['a']
['b', 'c']
```

I would like to get the total frequency of the `consequents` in all the `items` arrays like:

```
consequents  |  freq
___________   _______
['a']          2
['b']          2
['c']          1
```

How could I go about this?

I managed to make the items DF into one single row like

```
items
_____
[['a', 'b'], ['a'], ['b', 'c']]
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two dataframes using an `arrays_overlap` condition, then do a group by and count:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = (items.join(consequents, F.arrays_overlap('items', 'consequents'))
               .groupBy('consequents')
               .count()
         )

result.show()
+-----------+-----+
|consequents|count|
+-----------+-----+
|        [c]|    1|
|        [b]|    2|
|        [a]|    2|
+-----------+-----+
```

For older Spark versions (< 2.4) you can use an `array_contains` condition instead:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = (items.join(consequents, F.expr("array_contains(items, consequents[0])"))
               .groupBy('consequents')
               .count()
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us load the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'consequents':[['a'],['b'],['c']]})
dfi = pd.DataFrame({'items':[['a','b'],['a'],['b','c']]})
```

we note that `explode` is very useful in this context, eg check out the result of `dfi.explode('items')`. It may well be that what you want can be accomplished simply by

```
dfi.explode('items').value_counts()
```

that gives you

```
items
a        2
b        2
c        1
dtype: int64
```

But in case `dfi` has more elements than in `df` we can do a merge. So the final solution is simply

```
(df.explode('consequents')
  .merge(dfi.explode('items').value_counts().to_frame(), left_on = 'consequents', right_on = 'items')  
  .rename(columns = {0:'freq'})  
)
```

output

```
    consequents freq
0   a           2
1   b           2
2   c           1
```